# execute iplog.php on click of links

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am logging visitors IP by the following code below

```
$iplogfile = 'ips.txt';
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $webpage = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
            $timestamp = date('d/m/Y h:i:s');
            $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $fp = fopen($iplogfile, 'a+');
        chmod($iplogfile, 0777);
    fwrite($fp, '['.$timestamp.']: '.$ipaddress.' '.$webpage.' '.$browser. "\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

but i want it to be execute only when user clicks on this particular links

```
<a href="tel:+1 (000) 000-0000" class="btn-blue btn-red">Book Now</a>
<a href="tel:+1 (111) 111-1111" class="btn-blue btn-red">Call Now</a>
```

can someone help me out here? i cannot figure out how to acheive it :(

Thanks alot for your help and input.

Comment: These are client-side links only, nothing will be sent to the server when the user clicks on this. It will just attempt to open the user's registered app for phone calls. You'd need to have some JS or something to send an AJAX request to the server to log that it was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a function using [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) attribute in the HTML anghor tag. `onclick="myFunction()"`

```js
<a onclick="myFunction()" href="tel:+1 (000) 000-0000" class="btn-blue btn-red">Book Now</a>
<a onclick="myFunction()" href="tel:+1 (111) 111-1111" class="btn-blue btn-red">Call Now</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function myFunction()
{
    // add your code here
}

</script>
```

Comment: how would i execute the iplog.php there? please help out will appreciate it. Thanks a ton mate

Comment: @rosaline please check here.. https://www.delftstack.com/howto/php/onclick-php/

Comment: Please don't link to 3rd party sites, instead include fully working code in your answer. If the site you linked is unreachable this answer is of no real use. Thanks

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN really appreciate it alot it works like a charm :)

Comment: @brombeer Full answer is posted here, This link I share for additional help, Thank you for your concern...

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN im using this function

function logip(){
    $.ajax({url:"iplog.php", success:function(result){
    $("div").text(result);}
})
}  

but using it on multiple links it messes up the webpage

Comment: I think you should empty the div before putting text here.. ```$("div").text(result);```

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute this on clicking particular links then you should follow one of the following ideas as example:

1- Query strings, You can add a URL query parameter so you can check if it exists or not using $_GET, If it exists you can call your code.

2- You can create a new PHP file, Let's name it (track.php), And let's use AJAX to send requests to track.php on clicking the links you define using a class as example.

3- You can check what is the current path and URL and to set conditions using STRPOS to define whether the URL has the page you need to run the function for or not.

Comment: Would 1 and 3 work with a `tel:` link though? Don't think so

Comment: The second options is good for tel: links